# how to get "Done" button in android keyboard?

Tags: android

I created many emulators but i did not get 'Done' button on emulator.any ideas to solve this problem?
I have attached the screenshot [Emulator' Screenshot](http://thumbnails101.imagebam.com/23307/4eccae233062830.jpg)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just **add two lines** in **xml**:

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
android:singleLine="true"
```

**Done**

Comment: This should be the answer. singleLine attribute is a must for this to work.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` to your EditText.

Comment: I am facing this problem not for just my application.I am facing it in emulator.even when I open inbuilt application of Messaging etc.How to solve it?

Comment: @HirenPatel If you don't see the done button in inbuilt apps, then they have decided to not show it. There is nothing you can do about that.

Comment: but friend i want to do call searching functionality on Done button.

Comment: @HirenPatel You can only to that in your own app. You cannot force other apps to show the "done" button and listen for clicks on it

Comment: I want to do that functionality in my app but I am not able to see Done button in emulator.I have created avd.I don't know what is going wrong with avd.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the avd. The app you are opening simply doesn't ask the keyboard to show the done button. Simply write your own app that does.

Answer (score 0):

android:singleLine="true" has been deprecated. Alternatively you could use this:

```
android:inputType="text"
android:maxLines="1"
```